# search url with wildcard in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

Is there any way that i can search url with wildcard in ansible playbook.

I am trying this but getting error.
URL:http://10.100.120.8:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/Test/1.0-SNAPSHOT/new-1.0-*.jar
Dest:-----

Actual Path -
 http://10.100.120.8:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/Test/1.0-SNAPSHOT/new-1.0-2017/02/03-snapshot.jar

Comment: This requires [directory listing](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings), which is typically disabled nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no such mechanism.

Honestly I don't know any tools apart from pentest kits or site scrapers that support "url guessing".

If your http server support directory listing, you can fetch directory tree and search folders one by one.